# How to list all files in a given directory and subdirectories?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I want to take a path from the user and I want to list the file names of all the directories and sub directories in that path. So far, I was only able to get the file names for directories not subdirectories: 
I'm not allowed to use os.walk()

```
import sys, os.path

l = []
def fnames(path):
    global l
    l = os.listdir(path)
    print(l)


path = '/Users/sohamphadke/Desktop'

for i in l:
    if os.path.isdir(l) == True:
        fnames(l)
    elif os.path.isdir(l) == False:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

`glob` module is your answer!

You can access the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/glob.html), that say:

> If recursive is true, the pattern “`**`” will match any files and zero
>   or more directories, subdirectories and symbolic links to directories.
>   If the pattern is followed by an os.sep or os.altsep then files will
>   not match

So you could do:

```
import os
import glob
paths_list = glob.glob('/Users/sohamphadke/Desktop/**/*', recursive=True)

# Separate between files and directories
dirs_list = [path for path in paths_list if os.path.isdir(path)]
files_list = [path for path in paths_list if os.path.isfile(path)]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Soham Phadke Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) method, it will fetch you tree based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.walk` to walk through a path. Refer to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    print("root: {}\ndirs: {}\nfiles: {}".format(root, dirs, files))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use `pathlib`...

```
path = '/Users/sohamphadke/Desktop'

paths = Path(path).glob("**/*")
file_list = [p for p in paths if p.is_file()]
dir_list = [p for p in paths if p.is_dir()]
```

Notice `paths` is a generator, so you may iterate over each path and check if it's a file or a directory at a time.